# jQuery wildcard character in image source

Tags: jquery, replace, image, wildcard, src

I would like to change the src attribute of an image on click using jQuery. Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="view2">View 2</a>
<img src="images/shoe1a.jpg" class="sb-player" />
```

And in the img src, I want to replace the "a" to a "b," but my problem is that I want to ignore the "1" that's in front of it, since it could look like this as well:

```
<img src="images/shoe2a.jpg" class="sb-player" />
```

I got this far with my jQuery, and the asterisk is where I need a wildcard character:

```
$(function() {
    $('.view2').click(function() {
        $('.sb-player').attr('src', 'images/shoe'+*+'b.jpg');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Is there a certain character that could be a wildcard for any number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the entire end of the `src` string, replacing `a.jpg` with `b.jpg`.

You can pass a function [to `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

The parameter `i` represents the current iteration in the set, and `val` is the current value. The return value represents the new value.

```
$(function() {
    $('.view2').click(function() {
        $('.sb-player').attr('src', function(i,val) { 
             return val.replace('a.jpg','b.jpg');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The most powerful way to match any part of a string is using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) in javascript.

Maybe in this way you can solve your problem:

```
$(function() {
    $('.view2').click(function() {
        var originalSrc = $('.sb-player').attr('src');
        $('.sb-player').attr('src', originalSrc.replace(/a\./,"b."));
        return false;
    });
});
```